# How to add a suffix to an order number in Ruby

Tags: ruby, csv

I have a Ruby file that automatically turns customer orders from an eCommerce site into a CSV file. Different CSV files are printed according to different product vendors.

I need to add a suffix to the end of the order numbers for different vendors. For example, for a vendor named "Electric Styles", I need to add an `-ES` to the end of their order numbers. So future order numbers like `12345` should become `12345-ES`.

I believe I may have to add an `if`/`else` statement to the csvgen.rb file, Something like:

```
if(vendor = Electric styles){order-number-ES}
```

Not sure how to do this.

[image]

process2 file:

```
 This script processes the CSV files, it is executed when a CSV is detected in the Dropbox folder by run.rb 
# The ~/Dropbox/ORDERS/ARCHIVE/RUNNING/running.csv file contains all orders.

# Electric Styles
cat ~/Dropbox/*.csv | head -1 > ~/Dropbox/ORDERS/ElectricStyles.csv
grep -i -E "Electric Styles" *.csv >> ~/Dropbox/ORDERS/ElectricStyles.csv

awk -F, '{$14=$14*0.0352739619;print}' OFS=, ~/Dropbox/ORDERS/ElectricStyles.csv | awk -F, '{$14=$14==int($14)?int($14):int($14)+1}1' OFS=, | sponge ~/Dropbox/ORDERS/ElectricStyles.csv

cp ~/Dropbox/ORDERS/ElectricStyles.csv ~/Dropbox/ORDERS/ElectricStyles.$now.csv
rm ~/Dropbox/ORDERS/ElectricStyles.csv
cp ~/Dropbox/ORDERS/ElectricStyles*.csv ~/Dropbox/ORDERS/ElectricStyles/
cat ~/Dropbox/ORDERS/ElectricStyles/*.csv | sort -u -r > ~/Dropbox/ORDERS/ElectricStyles/RUNNING/running.csv
```

run.rb file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
`dropbox start`
while 1 == 1 do
  csvexists = !Dir.glob('/root/Dropbox/*.csv').empty?
  sleep(10)
  `proftpd`
  if csvexists == true
        sleep(10)
    `/root/Dropbox/process2`
  else
  end
end
```

csvgen.rb file:

```
csvgen.rb
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'mechanize'
require 'json'
require 'csv'

def every_n_seconds(n)
  loop do
    before = Time.now
    yield
    interval = n-(Time.now-before)
    sleep(interval) if interval > 0
  end
end

every_n_seconds(86400) do

web    = Mechanize.new
auth   = web.auth('xxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', domain = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx.myshopify.com')
count  = /\:(\d*)/.match(web.get("https://xxxxxxxxxxxx.myshopify.com/admin/orders/count.json").body).to_s.gsub(':','').to_i
pages  = count / 250 + 1
orders = []

catch :oldorder do 
  pages.times do |page|
    puts page
    order   = JSON.parse(web.get("https://xxxxxxxxxxx.myshopify.com/admin/orders.json?fields=order_number,created_at,shipping_address,shipping_lines,line_items&page=#{page}&limit=250").body)['orders']
    order.each do |order|
      date  = DateTime.iso8601(order["created_at"]).strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
      today = Date.today.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
      yestr = Date.today.prev_day.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
      throw :oldorder if date.to_s != today.to_s && date.to_s != yestr.to_s
      # throw :oldorder if order["order_number"] < 10000
      cust,ord,ord1 = [],[],[]
      unless order["shipping_lines"] == []
        cust << order["order_number"]
        cust << order["shipping_address"]["first_name"]
        cust << order["shipping_address"]["last_name"]
        cust << order["shipping_address"]["address1"]
        cust << order["shipping_address"]["address2"]
        cust << order["shipping_address"]["city"]
        cust << order["shipping_address"]["province_code"]
        cust << order["shipping_address"]["zip"]
        cust << order["shipping_address"]["country_code"]
        order["line_items"].each do |product|
          ord1 = product["title"],
                 product["variant_title"],
                 product["quantity"],
                 product["vendor"],
                 product["grams"],
                 order["shipping_lines"].first["code"],
                 product["sku"],
                 date
          ord << cust + ord1
        end
        ord.each do |o|
          orders << o
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

puts orders.count

`echo "Order Number,Shipping Address First Name,Shipping Address Last Name,Shipping Address Address 1,Shipping Address Address 2,Shipping Address City,Shipping Address Province code,Shipping Address Postal Code,Shipping Address Country code,Product Title,Product Variant Title,Product Quantity,Brand,Product Weight,Shipping Method,Product SKU,Created at" > /root/Dropbox/file.csv`

orders.each do |o|
  CSV.open("/root/Dropbox/file.csv", "a+:UTF-8") do |csv|
    csv << o
  end
end

end
```

Comment: It seems that you have two choices: get someone who knows Ruby to modify the Ruby code or write a program in whatever language you are comfortable with to modify the CSV file produced by the Ruby code. Someone here might suggest how `csvgen.rb` might be modified, but you will still need someone to make the changes with your specific requirements and test the modified code.

Answer (score 0):

In your csvgen.rb you need to modify

```
cust << order["order_number"]
```

to

```
cust << "#{order["order_number"]}-ES"
```

if `-ES` must be writed every time for every order.

If you need a dynamic `order_number` give an example row of the CSV file please.

Comment: I added a picture of an example row of the csv to the top of this page. 
Also the csvgen.rb file processes the orders for multiple vendors, so I'm not sure how to tell it only for 1 vendor to add -ES and not the others.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please use proper grammar, punctuation and formatting. SO isn't a message board or forum, it's more like an online reference book, and those things are significant. Also, if there's a question about what the OP means, ask, clarify the problem, then answer. Don't engage in a conversation trying to figure it out because that causes wandering questions and answers instead of conciseness.

Comment: I'm sorry for my formatting and grammar.
The picture is still not showing sample data and it should show where I can get the full name of vendor.